# Error related to headers and namespaces when migrating from C++/CX to C++/WinRT

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, cppwinrt

File.h:

```
std::map<winrt::hstring, winrt::hstring> someMap;
```

File.cpp

```
auto it = someMap.find(someKey);
if (it != someMap.end()) {
    it.second += (winrt::hstring{L", "} + someString.c_str());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
'second': is not a member of 'std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>'
    with
    [
        _Ty=std::pair<winrt::hstring,winrt::hstring>
    ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xtree(778): note: see declaration of 'std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>'
    with
    [
        _Ty=std::pair<winrt::hstring,winrt::hstring>
    ]
```

I know from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/move-to-winrt-from-cx#Header%20File%20Requirements) that one needs to include the headers of every namespace we consume. I am assuming this error is from there and maybe that's why Visual Studio is not able resolve to the find from std::map and instead maps to the find from xtree.h. But I might be wrong. I did try including std as a namespace, but that doesnt seem to work or atleast it seems like I might need something in addition to that. What headers and/or namespaces should I include for this error to be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) returns an iterator. An iterator doesn't have `first` or `second` members, unlike the actual items of the map. If you want to access the item, you need to dereference the iterator, either by using the `*` or the `->` operators:

```cpp
auto it = someMap.find(someKey);
if (it != someMap.end()) {
    it->second += (winrt::hstring{L", "} + someString.c_str());
}
```